# Decoding assembly from MSVC 32-bit release (homework). What does no-op do?

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++

Hi heads up this is a homework. I'm given an assembly generated by MSVC 32-bit Release with optimizations on, and I'm supposed to decode it back into C++. I've included the top of the function to the line I'm having problems with. The comments are mine, which I'm wrote while trying to understand this.

Note: Code is supposedly generated from C++. Not traditional ASM.
Note 2: There is one area of undefined behavior in the code.

Here are the lines I'm stuck with

```
TheFunction:                            ; TheFunction(int* a, int s);
0F2D4670  push  ebp                     ; Push/clear/save ebp
0F2D4671  mov   ebp,esp                 ; ebp now points to top of stack
0F2D4673  push  ecx                     ; Push/clear/save ecx
0F2D4674  push  ebx                     ; Push/clear/save ebs
0F2D4675  push  esi                     ; Push/clear/save esi

0F2D4676  mov   ebx,edx                         ; ebx = int s
0F2D4678  mov   esi,1                           ; esi = 1
0F2D467D  push  edi  ; calling convention       ; Push/clear/save edi
0F2D467E  mov   edi,dword ptr [a (0F2D95E8h)]   ; edi = a[0]
0F2D4684  cmp   ebx,esi                         ; if(s < 1)
0F2D4686  jl    SomeFunction+3Ch (0F2D46ACh)    ;   Jump to return
0F2D4688  nop   dword ptr [eax+eax]             ; !! <-- No op involving dereferencing?  What does this do?
0F2D4690  mov   eax,dword ptr [edi+esi*4-4]     ; !! <-- edi is *a, while esi is 1. There is no address 
here!
..... More code but I've figured these out ....
```

I've more or less got the gist of the function. Its a function that takes a pointer to an int, with an underlying array, and a size. It then goes through each element in the array from last to first, adding to each subsequent one and printing it out. However, I still haven't got the details down and need help

Two questions, both at the end of the code snippet. What does no op on a dereference pointer do, and am I reading the last line in that its attempting to dereference something not in memory?

Comment: Does `SomeFunction` change values of any registers like `esi`?

Comment: All the code is at above. @Ross_Ridge gave a pretty convincing answer down there!

Comment: The PUSH instructions don't clear or otherwise change the contents of the registers being pushed on the stack.

Comment: It is important to realize that a no-operation instruction does update the instruction-pointer/program-counter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `nop dword ptr [eax+eax]` instruciton does nothing.  It doesn't even access the memory location given by the operand.  It literally performs no operation.

It's just there so the next instruction is aligned to a 16-byte boundary. You'll notice that next instruction address is 0F2D4690 which ends with 0 which means it's 16-byte aligned. This can improve the performance of loops. Somewhere there will be an instruction that jumps back to 0F2D4690 as part of a loop. This particular form of a NOP instruction is used because it encodes a single NOP instruction in 8 bytes.

There is no corresponding C++ code for this instruction.  You shouldn't try to represent it in your C++ code, just ignore it.

Also note that your comment for `mov edi,dword ptr [a (0F2D95E8h)]` is incorrect.  Instead of being `edi = a[0]` it's simply `edi = a`.  The variable `a` isn't a parameter at all, instead it's a global (or file level static) variable located at memory location `0F2D95E8h`. This instruction just loads the value from memory.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That clears things up. What about the next line? Am I correct or wrong in that it is not dereferencing an address?

Comment: @user2418426 Your misunderstanding of what that line does is the result of a misunderstanding what a previous instruction does. I've updated my answer to explain that.

Comment: Saw your edit. That makes a lot of sense, but aren't pointers passed in registers? I know for a fact that the first two parameters should be passed on register, but I didn't know the type mattered.

Comment: Then why doesn't the edx (int s) get passed on the stack? Compiler optimization?

Comment: @user2418426: Can you include the actual machine code, or proper disassembly (just numbers and register names, not `a`)?  From the code addresses, we can see that `mov edi, dword ptr [a (0F2D95E8h)]` is 6 bytes long, so it can't be `mov edi, [ebp+8]`.  (That would be opcode + modrm + disp8 = 3 bytes).  I think it must include an absolute address or large offset (opcode + modrm + disp32 = 6 bytes), but IDK if the addressing mode includes a register or not.  If `s` is in EDX, we'd expect `a` in ECX (first arg in the `fastcall` calling convention).

Comment: @user2418426 Looking at the instruction more closely, it's not loading a function parameter at all. It's accesing a statically allocated variable, I've updated my answer.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry the entire assignment was on a word doc, so what you see is what I see. I could post the rest of the ASM code if you think it would help.

Comment: @user2418426: Oh, so you don't have an actual binary executable or object file, only this text disassembly?  But anyway, Ross's update makes sense, your prototype being wrong would fully explain the disassembly, and why the disassembler can attach a symbol name to an absolute address like that, and why there'd be such a large disp32.  It's just `mov edi, dword ptr [0F2D95E8h]`